# Python expanding the length of a for function inside the for function

Tags: python

I am running a program to parse data from a public website, it only allows me to view 14 pages in a given time period unless there is an error in which case I can view another page. If the error occurs, I am trying to expand the range that the for loop runs through. So far I have tried:

```
follow_range = 14


for i in range(0, follow_range):
      try:
          data_function          

      except:
          print("Failure in trying to view this data")

      follow_range = follow_range + 1
```

Unfortunately, it still only runs 14 times once it goes into the loop. What would be an alternative to solve this issue?

Comment: for this type of loop, use `while`.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to rely on the website to count up to 14, rather than have your own counter which might get out of sync with the website for whatever reason; or the website might change the limit in the future. Write a `while True:` loop to keep making requests, and use `break` to get out of the loop when the website tells you you've used up your request limit.

Comment: `for` isn't a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use a `while` loop:

```
follow_range = 14
i = 0

while i < follow_range:
      try:
          data_function 
          i += 1
      except:
          print("Failure in trying to view this data")
```

This way `i` will sum 1 whenever the function is successful, otherwise it will remain at its original value, hence allowing you 14 successful passes of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a `for` loop in this case.  A `while` loop will suit you better, because you don't really know how many times you want to iterate

Modifying your example

```
follow_range = 14
count = 0

while count < follow_range:
      try:
          data_function
          count += 1 # note the change in syntax here as an example        

      except:
          print("Failure in trying to view this data")
```

I made a change to the syntax using the `+=` operator as that is better practice when modifying a variable by adding to it

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend that you provide more context for your question and more relevant code. It would be great to see the API calls you're making and if you're using a framework like Flask/Django. The API you're requesting data from may also have some helpful information like the number of pages remaining or the number of pages total.

Typically, a for loop (this is true of most languages) is intended to be used in cases where you have a specific, static number of iterations. Even if the number of iterations is unknown (the length of a list retrieved from a server, for instance), it is usually still static.

The reason this isn't working is because `range(0, follow_range)` is creating a static `Iterable` object. Adding something to `follow_range` won't work as it might in js, because the range function has already been run and the number of iterations has already been set.

That being said, I recommend you do one of the following:

1. Continue using your for loop but implement `data_function` in such a way that it has its own error handling and retry logic.
2. Use a while loop to continue requesting data until there are no more pages.

Answer (score -3):

Increment the "followrange" variable in the exception block, not outside.

Comment: This won't work at all, because the `range` object has already been created before the first iteration of the loop, and changing `follow_range` won't change the state of that `range` object.

Comment: Right, I forgot. Sorry